# SwiftUI Canvas : how to reinstall app used by canvas?

Tags: xcode, canvas, swiftui

Canvas in Xcode always crashs and can not preview anymore (on all Views). But when I change iOS Simulator, canvas works again.

I've clicked on Diagnostics button to get log. And it appears that it crashs because a table in my SQLite file is missing a column. Indeed, I've just added this column.

As I understand, Canvas is using a simulator to build and run previews. So I think Canvas uses an old version of my SQLite database (that is created when app is freshly installed) and I want to reinstall app that is used for preview rendering.

Using Product -> Clean Build Folder does not remove app from Canvas. Removing app from iOS Simulator neither.

Question is : How do you remove app and data from "Canvas simulator" ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to delete app and data from Canvas simulator. It will force Canvas to "reinstall" app and, in this particular case, recreate SQLite database with correct columns.

1. Quit Xcode
2. Go into `/Users/<your username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Previews/Simulator Devices`.
3. Find which device is crashing (read log from Diagnostics in Canvas can help you find simulator ID).
4. In device folder, you will find a `data` folder. Rename it (`data_OLD` for example).
5. Restart Xcode and try using Canvas preview. It will recreate `data` folder and it should work.

This can be used to reinstall apps used by Canvas.